# Call parent constructor in java

Tags: java, constructor

I have two class `Parent` and `Child`, while the `Parent` have a constructor which needs 3 arguments:

```
class Parent{
    public Parent(String host,String path,int port){
    }
}
```

And now I want the `Child` constructor need only one argument, then I try to do something like this:

```
class Child extend Parent{
    public Child(String url){
        String host=getHostFromUrl(url);
        String path=....
        String port=...
        super(host,path,port);
    }
}
```

But this does not work.

Any idea to fix it?

BTW, I have no access to `Parent` class.

Comment: super must be the first statemenr

Comment: That's why I ask this question, because I have to process the url first. :)

Comment: see the alternative provided by Sir Jon Skeet's answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The call to `super` *must* be the first statement in the constructor body. From [section 8.8.7 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7):

> The first statement of a constructor body may be an explicit invocation of another constructor of the same class or of the direct superclass (§8.8.7.1).

You just need to inline the calls:

```
public Child(String url) {
    super(getHostFromUrl(url), getPathFromUrl(url), getPortFromUrl(url));
}
```

Alternatively, parse *once* to some cleaner representation of the URL, and call another constructor in the same class:

```
public Child(String url) {
    this(new URL(url));
}

// Or public, of course
private Child(URL url) {
    super(url.getHost(), url.getPath(), url.getPort());
}
```

(I haven't checked whether those members would work for `java.net.URL` - this is more by way of an approach than the details. Adjust according to your actual requirements.)

Comment: But one more problem, is it possible to avoid the exception in the constructor? Since the `new URL(url)` may throw exception, then the caller of the `Child` have to handle the exception.

Comment: @hguser: Well what do you *want* to happen if the string isn't a valid URL? You could write a static method to wrap the exception in an unchecked exception if you want, but fundamentally you need to consider the failure cases.

Comment: I try to consume the exception internally rather to the caller, `a static method` sounds like good, I will have a try :)

Comment: As we can see in here, questions will follow because you are giving people ready-to-use things. He must read and learn. I don't have a problem with your solution in fact i gave a point to it. But blaming everyone who does not giving entire code is a bad thing.

Comment: @hguser: So you're going to swallow the exception entirely? I would *strongly* advise against that. Making it an unchecked exception is reasonable, but I wouldn't expect `new Child("")` to just return... what could `new Child("").getPort()` sensibly return, for example? (Assuming `Parent` gives me that ability.)

Comment: @CemOzer: The follow-on question here wouldn't be answered by reading the page you referred to. Not supplying full code is okay (although non-ideal) if the post still answers the question. Answering by basically repeating the compile-time error message (admittedly with a link) simply isn't particularly helpful, IMO. It doesn't give any indication of how to solve the problem of needing to extract values before calling the superconstructor.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
public class Parent {
  public Parent(String host, String path, int port) {
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  public Child(String url) {
    super(getHost(url), getPath(url), getPort(url));
  }

  static String getHost(String url) {
    // Logic to calculate host
    return url;
  }

  static String getPath(String url) {
    // Logic to calculate path
    return url;
  }

  static int getPort(String url) {
    // Logic to calculate port
    return 8080;
  }
}
```

Comment: why would these methods be static?

Comment: @Java1: They have to be - otherwise you can't use them in an explicit call to super/this. Also, they clearly don't need any state from the instance, so why *wouldn't* they be static methods? They don't need to public, mind you.

Comment: You get error "Cannot refer to an instance method while explicitly invoking a constructor"